# Reentrancy on a Single-Threaded Application

Tags: .net, asynchronous, com, thread-safety, activex

Writing a Winforms application over .NET 4.0 (using VB2010). It has a single form, including an ActiveX COM control asynchronously raising events. The events are handled by hook functions on form's code-file. Application does NOT start any threads (except the main one, ofcourse).

Should I guard from event-handler reentrancy?
Could Event **B**'s hook-function be called while Event **A**'s hook-function is being executed?

{ Searching the web has raised several conflicting answers. I'm puzzled here... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not any different for ActiveX controls versus .NET controls.  Whatever you do in the event A event handler that affects the control may certainly cause another event to be raised.  Or event A may be raised again.  Another event rarely causes trouble but the latter case usually causes this site's name exception.  And you fix it the same way, a bool field that prevents re-entry.

The underlying mechanics are identical.  An ActiveX control too can fire an event in a property setter.  That doesn't have anything to do with threading or a single threaded apartment.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply.  I added info in a comment above. Isn't there an underlying mechanism for buffering fired events while a previously intercepted event is being handled?
Back in DOS days (as well as today, on embedded systems), I could disable-interrupts when entering a function, and re-enable them before function return, and by that make the function atomic.
Is there a similar "disable-events" mechanism?

Comment: There is no "master switch".  An event is not much like an interrupt, you can ignore an interrupt for a while.  That's not possible for an event.  Do consider that you might be worrywarting about this too much.

Comment: I could use the `Interlocked` class to prevent Event-reentrancy, right? Could it also be used to make sure events are handled **in the order they were fired**?
Could `SyncLock` be simply used for this purpose?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with threads.  No point in using Interlocked, there is never an issue about event order, everything runs on one thread.  The UI thread.  A simple bool suffices to detect re-entrancy.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. My question regards the following steps, once re-entrancy was detected: how do I deal with it such that events are NOT thrown and are handled in their firing order? Would a busy-waiting loop on that boolean be sufficient? something like `while (bWait == true);  bWait = true;  Guarded Section;  bWait = false;`

Comment: No.  Why don't you actually practice with one.  Use a TextBox, implement its TextChanged event and append a character to the Text property in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which ActiveX control and which events are involved the answer can only be rather general:

You should always handle any reentrancy in a graceful way.
You can either "throw away" any reentry OR you can handle them in parallel OR you can "queue" them and handle them one after the other...

Without further details I don't see a way to be more specific :-(

Comment: Thanks. The COM ActiveX control I'm using is actually an API to a remote server. By calling its methods, commands are sent to the remote server. The events it raises are basically data retrieved from the server. Each event-handler in my code performs a series of procedural calls (i.e. synchronous) within event-context. I must be able to make sure that while a certain event is being processed, no other event shall be intercepted by the application. I thought that a single-threaded application is not be vulnerable to reentrance, but now I understand this is not necessarily correct.

Comment: What could be done to prevent re-entrance?
If it's of any interest, the control I'm using is IB (Interactive Brokers) ActiveX API.

Comment: @Bliss your goal ist still not really clear... do you want to "throw away" any events happening while you you are processing an event OR do you want to queue for further processing ?

Comment: Events must NOT be thrown. They should be queued for later handling, preferably by any existing Windows / .NET mechanism (e.g. buffering all events fired while a previously-intercepted event is being processed).

Comment: @Bliss there is no such mechanism... you will have to build one yourself - by using one queue per event (for example `ConcurrentQueue`) to store all event-specific information and then process the content of the queue... to build a sentinel you could utilize `Interlocked` class...

Comment: Shall look it through. +1 for the useful tip. Thanks!

Comment: One more (important) thing regarding your "queue per event" solution: Mustn't the operation of addition to queue be atomic?? Consider a case in which while queuing a certain event (within the **Queue.Add** function), the same event-handler is reentered, causing queue structure-inconsistency.

Comment: @Bliss yes, it must... that is why I mentioned `ConcurrentQueue` which handles this correctly and efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. I think I shall 1st give a try to the Interlocked class.  :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19705/discussion-between-bliss-and-yahia)